# using locks in a game with threads

Tags: java, multithreading, locking, game-development

I am trying to debug some code for a space invaders type game where there are 20 alien ships that we have to shoot. The game displays the number of ships that are currently on the screen. When you shoot and destroy a ship, the total number of ships should decrement by 1 for each ship destroyed. So for 20 ships, when you shoot all 20 the display should say "0" for the number of ships left. However, for some reason that I do not understand, when I shoot all 20 ships, the display will show "-2" or "-3" which makes no sense to me since there can't be a negative number of ships.

I tried to fix this solution with a `ReentrantLock` since this game uses multiple threads, but don't really know quite how to do this properly. Here is the segment that checks to see if an alien ship and bullet collide (which is when the ship should be destroyed):

```
public void checkCollisions() 
{
   //check for alien ship and bullet collisions
   for (AlienShip a : aships) 
   {
     if (a.isAlive()) 
     {
        //check for bullet collisions
        for (Bullet bullet : bullets)
        {
           if (bullet.isAlive()) 
           {
              //perform the collision test
              if (a.getBounds().contains(bullet.getX(), 
                                         bullet.getY()))
              {
                 bullet.setAlive(false);
                 a.setAlive(false);
                 shipLock.lock();
                 try
                 {
                    int shipCount = aliveShips;
                    shipCount--;
                    aliveShips = shipCount;
                 }
                 finally
                 {
                    shipLock.unlock();
                 }
                 continue;
             }
          }
       }
    }
}
```

Comment: Depends a lot on which threads do what in your system. Is there more then 1 calling this method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is it possible for multiple bullets to hit the same ship in the same frame?  In classic space invaders you only have one bullet, however you are processing a list so this is not the same.
If two bullets hit the same ship, your inner loop "for (Bullet bullet : bullets)" will process both bullets hitting the ship and even though the ship is dead the second bullet will decrease the counter again.
If you replace the 'continue' with a 'break' then the bullet loop will stop when the ship is killed, this might be your intention?

Comment: Yes that is my intention. When the bullet is killed by 1 bullet, it decreases the counter. I switched the `continue` to a `break` and it worked. Thank you so much. How did you know to switch it from a continue to a break?

Comment: 'continue' will just jump to the end of the enclosing loop and then *continue* the loop.  'break' will *break* out of the enclosing loop.  At least, that's how I remember them :)  If my answer is correct, please hit the 'accept answer' button.